# if $-a\leq b\leq a$, then $|b|\leq a$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

if $-a\leq b\leq a$, then $|b|\leq a$

I started by showing that $-|b|\leq b\leq |b|$, but then I can only see that $a$ can be equal to $|b|$, how do I show $|b|\leq a$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $b\geq 0$, then $|b|=b$ and we are given $b\leq a$.

If $b<0$, then we have $|b|=-b$. We are given $-a\leq b$, which is the same as $a\geq -b$, but in this case we have $-b=|b|$, so in this case we have $a\geq |b|$.

Either way, $|b|\leq a$.