# Prove that for all real numbers $a$ and $b$, $|a|\leq b$ iff $-b\leq a\leq b$.

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, solution-verification

Not a duplicate of

[If $a\leq b$ and $-a\leq b$, then $|a|\leq b$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3296820/if-a-leq-b-and-a-leq-b-then-a-leq-b)

[if $-a\leq b\leq a$, then $|b|\leq a$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1645219/if-a-leq-b-leq-a-then-b-leq-a)

[Is my proof of $|a| \leq b \iff -b \leq a \leq b$ correct?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3736979/is-my-proof-of-a-leq-b-iff-b-leq-a-leq-b-correct)

[Prove that for all real numbers $a$ and $b$, $|a| \leq b$ iff $-b \leq a \leq b$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3609421/prove-that-for-all-real-numbers-a-and-b-a-leq-b-iff-b-leq-a-leq-b)

This is exercise $3.5.12.a$ from the book *How to Prove it* by Velleman $($$2^{nd}$ edition$)$:

Prove that for all real numbers $a$ and $b$, $|a|\leq b$ iff $-b\leq a\leq b$.

I am familiar with the routine proof of the above theorem but I was wondering whether we could prove the right-to-left direction of the above theorem in the following simple way:

Suppose $-b\leq a\leq b$. Since $a\leq b$ then $a\leq b$ or $-a\leq b$ and thus by definition $|a|\leq b$. Therefore if $-b\leq a\leq b$ then $|a|\leq b$. $Q.E.D.$

I am suspicious of my proof! Is it correct$?$ If not, then why$?$

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: This is not at all correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you said "Since $a\le b$ then $a\le b$ or $-a\le b$",

you should have said since $a\le b$ then $a\le b$ and since $-b\le a$ then $b\ge -a$.

Comment: I know that but my conclusion is of the form $P$ or $Q$. I have $P$. Am I not allowed to conclude without justification that $P$ or $Q?$

Comment: To prove $|a|\le b$, you really need $P$ *and* $Q$

Comment: So why when we prove the left-to-right direction, we break it up into cases as if it is $P$ or $Q?$

Comment: $P$ and $Q$ implies $P$ or $Q$, but not the reverse